# Projects sets in RubyMine

Tags: rubymine

Is there a way to create project groups or slt.

**Example:** I work on applications which consists from multiple applications. I would like to be able to open all the projects related to that one application *at once*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported in the current version but may become available later, follow [this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-5324) for the updates.